# API code to Google Shotern URL

Tags: api

I want **API** code to shotern url to goo.gl. I want to develop program in visual basic with module. I already made an application of tiny url it works fine but now I want it for goo.gl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/getting_started#shorten)

POST a json object to https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url
Content-Type: application/json

{"longUrl": "http://www.google.com/"}
```

The response is also JSON.

```
{
 "kind": "urlshortener#url",
 "id": "http://goo.gl/fbsS",
 "longUrl": "http://www.google.com/"
}
```

curl example:

```
curl https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{"longUrl": "http://www.google.com/"}'
```

Answer (score 1):

hyePOST https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url
Content-Type: application/json

{"longUrl": "http://www.google.com/"}